# Python Readline on macOS behaves differently than on Linux/Windows

Tags: python, macos, gnu, readline

A project I'm working on uses a custom CLI handler instead of Python's `cmd.Cmd` class.  Without getting too much in detail, the handler features TAB-key completion to assist the operator with command usage.  The feature works as expected on Windows (using `pyreadline`) and Linux (using GNU's `readline`).

Here is an example of the expected behavior (assume "cmd > " is the prompt and that [TAB] is a push of the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key):

```
cmd > [TAB]
cd exit load save                        # all the available commands
cmd > c[TAB]                             # autocompletes to 'cd'
cmd > cd [TAB]
cd ./folder1 cd ./folder2 cd ./folder3   # folders in the cwd
cmd > cd C:\[TAB]
cd C:\Users cd C:\Windows...             # enumerates folders in C:\ (on windows)
cmd > cd /[TAB]
cd /bin cd /opt cd /usr...               # enumerates folders from root (on linux)
```

The custom class defines the following tab completion method, which is set using `readline.set_completer()`:

```
def tab_completer(self, text, state):
    # rl delims set to "" so we get the whole line as a single string
    words = re.split(r'[\s\t\n]+', text)
    # find_subcompleter populates a list of possible matches or next words
    # each command implements its own completer_stub depending on the function (ex: cd will complete directory names)
    retval = self.find_subcompleter(words.pop())
    try:
        return retval[state]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

The function works as expected on Windows (10, Python 3.6.6) and Linux (CentOS 7, Python 3.6.8), but something strange happens on macOS (10.15.7, Python 3.8.2 via xcode on zsh terminal):

```
cmd > [TAB]
cd exit load save    # this is good
cmd > c[TAB]         # still autocompletes to 'cd', good
cmd > cd [TAB]
cd exit load save    # as if I've typed nothing!
```

For those of you wondering, this behavior happens with ANY command, not just with `cd`.

I'm aware that the underlying `readline` implementation on macOS uses `libedit` due to GNU licensing.  I just haven't seen anyone else (to date) mention this difference on any other forums.  A possible solution that comes to mind is to add a conditional for `libedit` implementations to use `get_line_buffer()` and `redisplay()` to mimic the correct behavior.  Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated!

Thank you